# How to keep only the CSS classes you are using from a ready multi-purpose template?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have bought a HTML multi-purpose template that is really huge with a lots of css and js files.
What I want to use from it it is just a small percentage of what the template offers. For example because it is multi-purpose it has about 70 different different sections to use.

This results in a huge size of calculated css files and I want to avoid this.
My question, is there any "smart" way to create a CSS file that contains only the classes that I am using to make the page faster?
Also, is this something applicable to JS files?

Thank you

Comment: downvoter should write why. This community is getting worse day by day...

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new CSS file, copy every section that I want to use in the new file and refer in the HTML file to the new one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"/>
```

I am new to HTML programing but that is how I created my first page.
Also did the same for the JS file. Downloaded a free sample with some text checking scripts and only kept what i needed for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no easy way to isolate the CSS, you have to identify and extract the code you need and place it in a separate file, as yhings go for JS, you will have to divide the scripts in separate snippets to make things easier for you...but you will have to read and structure each line of code.

GOOD LUCK!